# Need SQL script to check long ops sessions as well as it's CPU consumption that is running for more than 15mins

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

We are getting a lot of long ops alerts that get triggered if the session is running for more than 15mins. But not all of them are resource consuming for CPU.

So to limit the number of alerts we are getting, I want to add CPU consumption to the long ops alert SQL query.

A SQL script to check my long ops sessions that have been there for more than 15 mins and also a condition to check sessions that are consuming CPU greater than 50% in those long ops sessions is what I need. Kindly help.

Query to check long ops running more than 15mins that I am using:

```
SELECT count(*) as long_running_count FROM V$SESSION_LONGOPS 
WHERE username is not NULL and totalwork > 0 and SOFAR <> TOTALWORK 
and OPNAME NOT LIKE '%aggregate%' AND (SYSDATE - start_time)2460 > 15;
```

Comment: Join your query with `V$SESSTAT` using `SID` to find out the CPU Utilization by each session. You can then put a filter for those session consuming more than 50%.

Comment: @XING - I would really need some help there. I queried V$SESSTAT but I'm not really good with the join or combining the outputs of these two queries to get the required output.